# How to detect Wall Collision and Rotate Robot by 90 degrees?

Tags: java, collision, simulator

so recently, we've been assigned to code multiple circles that act like robots in a GUI interface. Basically, a robot simulator.

I've got the code to spawn in multiple circles that can act like robots.

This is my current code for detecting wall collision between the robot and the end of the square:

```
private void checkCollisions(double maxX, double maxY) {

for (ListIterator<Ball> slowIt = balls.listIterator(); slowIt.hasNext();) {
        Ball b1 = slowIt.next();
        // check wall collisions:
        double xVel = b1.getXVelocity();
        double yVel = b1.getYVelocity();
        if ((b1.getCenterX() - b1.getRadius() <= 0 && xVel < 0)
                || (b1.getCenterX() + b1.getRadius() >= maxX && xVel > 0)) {
            b1.setXVelocity(-xVel);
        }
        if ((b1.getCenterY() - b1.getRadius() <= 0 && yVel < 0)
                || (b1.getCenterY() + b1.getRadius() >= maxY && yVel > 0)) {
            b1.setYVelocity(-yVel);
        }
        for (ListIterator<Ball> fastIt = balls.listIterator(slowIt.nextIndex()); fastIt.hasNext();) {
            Ball b2 = fastIt.next();

            final double deltaX = b2.getCenterX() - b1.getCenterX() ;
            final double deltaY = b2.getCenterY() - b1.getCenterY() ;
            if (colliding(b1, b2, deltaX, deltaY)) {
                bounce(b1, b2, deltaX, deltaY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The

```
b1.setXVelocity(-xVel);  

b1.setYVelocity(-yVel);
```

are the main bits that make the circle bounce back from the wall. However, instead of this, I want the ball to detect the wall and rotate 90 degrees rather than bounce back form the wall like a bouncing ball.

Any help will be fully appreciated or a working piece of code that ca do this for me. I have an AraryList of all the balls called 'balls'.

If needed, I can give source code.

This is what I have so far. But I need each ball to have a sensor attached to them detecting if there a wall ahead.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsQvX.png

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have just square walls:

If the ball hits the right wall for example, you want to remove all x velocity, and then add either positive or negative velocity.

The issue with this is that the robot will end up just going around the outside edges of the map.

Comment: yeahh, its a weird situation unless there's a different way to do it with like a sensor coming out of the circle which detects if there's a wall infront of it, and so rotates it? but im not sure how to do that